# I need multiple calculations in a single statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT PrisID, 
       Navn, 
       [Vægt (g)], 
       [RåvarePris(øre)], 
       Produktionsomk, 
       [RåvarePris(øre)] + Produktionsomk AS NettoPris, 
       NettoPris * 25 AS Moms, 
       NettoPris + Moms AS PrisInclMoms, 
       PrisInclMoms * 100 AS [Pris(100gr)]
FROM PrislisteBolsjer
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use aliases in the same filed list as they are created.

You can use `cross apply` to do the calculation that you need to reuse.

```
SELECT PrisID, 
       Navn, 
       [Vægt (g)], 
       [RåvarePris(øre)], 
       Produktionsomk, 
       T1.NettoPris, 
       T2.Moms, 
       T3.PrisInclMoms, 
       T3.PrisInclMoms * 100 AS [Pris(100gr)]
FROM PrislisteBolsjer
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT [RåvarePris(øre)] + Produktionsomk) AS T1(NettoPris)
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT T1.NettoPris * 25) AS T2(Moms)
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT T1.NettoPris + T2.Moms) AS T3(PrisInclMoms)
```

Comment: @ErikLindbøg-Løfgreen – You are welcome. If it does what you want you should consider accepting the answer. Read more about it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work